# Results change depending on whether set.seed is specified before or after loading RData file containing .Random.seed

Tags: r, random-seed

I am running an `R` script that reads an external `RData` file.  I am attempting to modify that `R` script to run without using that `RData` file to improve generality.

I discovered that the results returned by the script differ depending on whether I use a `set.seed` statement immediately before or immediately after loading the `RData` file.  I also discovered that the `RData` file contains a vector called `.Random.seed`.  Otherwise the `RData` file only contains data as far as I can tell, not any functions or code.

The mere presence of the `.Random.seed` vector in the `RData` file appears to change the results of random number generators (`runif`, `rnorm`, etc.) or `sample` statements in the script that appear after I load the `RData` file even though I never refer to this `.Random.seed` vector in the script.

How can I reproduce the results of the script that contains the `RData` file without actually including the `RData` file in the script?

```
load("CPT CAL.RData")
.Random.seed[1:5]
#[1]         403         493 -1955963110 -1150619109   212268921
sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 100  60  76  39   7  57  28  85  89  73

sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 81 89 15  4 60 32 58 71 62 17

sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 18 46 89 66 23 24 24 41 37 70

##################################

# Here I try to reproduce the above results using the first element
# of the .Random.seed vector as a seed but this does not work
set.seed(403)
sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 44 31 23 83 16 27 71 64 13 18

sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 86 54 46 25 65 42 76 49 46 50

sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 44 44 90 39 46 14 41 52 36 63
```

Comment: You can't just use the "403" part of the vector. The Random.seed is the whole vector. But every time you draw a random number, the .Random.seed vector changes. It's really the random number generator state, not the initial seed. Presumably the value in the rdata file is the random seed at the end of simulation. There's no way to figure out what it was at the beginning of the simulation. You would have needed to have saved that value explicitly. If you restore the `.Random.seed` from an rdata file, every "random" value after that will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  I am thinking the only way to reproduce the results is to put a set.seed statement in the original code immediately after the RData file is loaded.  Save the output and use those results as my target to check my subsequent code modifications.

Answer (score 1):

@MrFlick posted a very clear and very helpful explanation for why my original attempt at a solution did not work.

Subsequently I arrived at a solution adequate for my purposes.  I placed a `set.seed` statement immediately after loading the `RData` file into the original `R` script.  I saved the results as my target values.

Then I added the same `set.seed` statement into my revised version of the `R` script that never loads the `RData` file.

Both approaches returned the same results.